# Custom number in MS Access

Tags: sql, vba, database, ms-access, ms-access-2016

Am a newbie in **Microsoft Access 2016** making a **database system for processing loans.**
I have made two fields:

1. **ID** *e.g: **001*** with datatype **number** and
2. **NRC** (*This is the official National Registration Card number in my country e.g: "**123456/78/1**" )*

I now want to generate a new field:

3. **LoanNumber** from the fields 1. **ID** and 2. **NRC** mentioned above.
   From the examples above, I want this new field to be composed with two parts concatenated together; that is  "**ID**-first part of **NRC** before the first '/' ".

e.g: **LoanNumber** : **001-123456**

What code in the expression builder will will help me achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

A number datatype value cannot be saved with preceding zeros. Use Format function to manipulate number. This can be done in a query or textbox but not in table because Format function is not available for Calculated field type.

`Format([ID], "000-") & Left([NRC], 6)`

Comment: If answer resolves issue, please mark accepted. Upvote is always nice as well.